# Why hive automatically adds comment 'from deserializer' to fields when I use a custom serde？

Tags: hive

I wrote a custom serde and used it when building the table, but when I 'show create table', the field was set to comment 'from deserializer'. How can I remove this comment. Where is it generated in the source code?